# Identify whether an icon represents a package or file

Tags: applications, finder

There are some way to know, by the icon, if it's a package (like a .app) or a single file? I'm talking about some app or config that adds a flag in the icon, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Control- or right-clicking a package in Finder will show the context menu item `Show Package Contents`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the Finder.  In Finder's preferences go to 'Advanced' and tick 'Show all filename extensions'.  After you do this if something is an application it will have a .app after it's name.

[image: Screenshot of the preference + its effects]

Comment: But apps are not the only packages.

Comment: The problem then becomes being computer literate enough to be able to tell which extensions refer to files, and which to packages ;)